# How to consume S3 events from SQS with Celery?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, celery, amazon-sqs

I'm looking for a way to extend Celery so it can pick up messages from SQS that are left there by other services (S3 for example). These messages have an arbitrary format, so I would need to parse them and transform them into what Celery expects.

My initial idea is to write a custom [serializer](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v2.2.6/userguide/executing.html#executing-serializers), but I would love to hear other approaches.

I am aware that I can put a custom solution in the middle (like a lambda function) that basically processes the events and schedules celery tasks from them, but ideally I would like to avoid this extra step, specially considering that Celery is already able to use SQS as a broker.

Comment: I would strongly advise you not to do this. Celery is not designed to be an arbitrary MQ consumer. - Just because it may be possible to do something that it is not made for does not mean we should do it.

Comment: Yeah, I also had that feeling. I don't know exactly how many parts of Celery actually expect the messages in the queue to have that specific format and if all of them access the messages through the serializer. Thanks for your input.